# How can i fetch Requesting server hostname from requested server?

Tags: php, curl

I am using **curl** to transfer data between two servers. For ex: My servers are: **www.server1.com** and **www.server2.com**

**www.server1.com** uses curl like:

```
$ch = curl_init( $url );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $myvars);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$response = curl_exec( $ch );
```

How can i know that this request is initiated from **www.server1.com** and not other servers on my second server **www.server2.com**? I am not geeting **HTTP_ORIGIN** at my second server so that i came to know that request came from which server without security violence.

I came to know the option to transfer an **HTTP_REFERER** in curl like

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, "http://example.com/aboutme.html");
```

However, user can change this host to anything. So if any client server is not registered with us and uses this, will allowed to access my server.

So is there any secure way to do so with curl??

Any help is appreciated please.

Thanks.

Comment: Check if the IP address (`$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']`) is the same as `www.server1.com`.

Comment: That can not be possible in case of shared hosting servers..